# Android app crashes when trying to receive a response from an activity after the screen has been rotated

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm writing an application that has a main activity that on creation sends the intent to use the standard camera app. The camera app takes a picture and returns the result to the main activity, which then decides on the action to perform. If the screen is rotated while the camera app is on, it fails to return a response to the main activity, otherwise it works flawlessly. Here follows the code structure

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private Uri fileUri;

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent

                <do stuff>

                // Open the image
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the log

```
07-14 19:11:10.768: E/BitmapFactory(22377): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/IMG_20140714_191110.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377): Process: com.domain.myapp, PID: 22377
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.domain.myapp/com.domain.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.domain.myapp/com.domain.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2774)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3724)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.domain.myapp/com.domain.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2761)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    ... 13 more
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at com.domain.myapp.MainActivity.draw_interface(MainActivity.java:97)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at com.domain.myapp.MainActivity.draw(MainActivity.java:188)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at com.domain.myapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:234)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
07-14 19:11:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(22377):    ... 14 more
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/BitmapFactory(23317): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myapp/IMG_20140714_191308.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317): Process: com.domain.myapp, PID: 23317
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.domain.myapp/com.domain.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.domain.myapp/com.domain.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2774)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3724)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.domain.myapp/com.domain.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2761)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    ... 13 more
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.domain.myapp.MainActivity.draw_interface(MainActivity.java:97)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.domain.myapp.MainActivity.draw(MainActivity.java:188)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.domain.myapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:234)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
07-14 19:13:08.278: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: can you please post your full logcat

Comment: or at least what the actual npe is (and any lines associated with the problem)

Comment: the problem is in onActivityResult, as indicated by the "Failure delivering result". It seems that the camera app won't create the picture, whose existence is assumed by the rest of the application. This is why there is a FileNotFound exception. File manager confirms the referenced file doesn't get created, while everything works with the same code if the screen is not rotated. Or if the screen is rotated and the rotated back before giving control back to the main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when screen rotates on Create method is getting called everything is just reinitialize so make sure you are initializing all your variables again  and stating the whole process again.

Comment: the main activity is basically empty at the moment, apart from a "hello world" text entry and the action bar. Nothing needs to be saved or restored afaik.

Comment: I noticed that the camera intent was replicated on rotation (the back key led to another camera preview), so I realized that the intent should be avoided if there is a non null state for my app. So your answer turned out to be the correct one. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the screen will cause the Activity to be destroyed and created again, unless you specify otherwise.

To prevent that destruction and re-creation on screen rotate, add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the Activitys entry in AndroidManifest. It will look something like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.mpascual.example.IncallActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

edit: I just added `keyboardHidden` to show you how you can set multiple values (in case you need it)

Comment: I just tried your solution but it didn't work in my case. As I pointed out above the camera app doesn't produce any picture if the screen is rotated while the camera preview is on

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood you question. Could you try adding *android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"* to the *application* tag of AndroidManifest?

Comment: Even if this solves the problem, imho I think it is a good practice to let the DVM take care of memory usage, so preventing the app from being destroyed while in the background doesn't seem to me very neat. The solution proposed by @akash-yadav works fine, I just needed to restore one variable and use and if ... else ... stmt. Thanks for your help anyway, much appreciated.

Comment: ¿? Let the DVM take care of memory usage? I was not proposing anything like that. Would it solve your problem or not, please take note that this wouldn't take memory management away from Dalvik; it would only change the lifecycle of the activity. Anyway, I'm glad that @akash yadav read your question quite better than me. Congrats.